# How to Mock getSting Resource in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a resource so in my production code whenever

```
getString(R.string.res1)
```

the following data will be returned:

```
"aaa"
```

this is what I tried so far:

```
class Product{
    fun start(){
        val x = getString(R.string.res1)
        ... // rest of the code
    }
}


class ProductTest{
    @Mock
    lateinit var mockContext: Context

    @Test
    fun test_isCorrect(){
        `when`(mockContext.getString(R.string.res1)).thenReturn("aaa")
        Product().start()
    }


}
```

each time I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: getString(R.string.res1) must not be null
```

I expect the getString(R.string.res1) will result in giving "aaa" in return, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

What ever is happening with `Product().start()` is not receiving `mockContext` so the context inside is another reference, is a unmocked reference.

```
class Product{
    fun start(context: Context? = null){
        val safeContext = context ?: //get the context as you already do for using the getString method
        val x = safeContext.getString(R.string.res1)
        ... // rest of the code
    }
}
```

So then you have to pass the mocked `Context`

```
@Test
fun test_isCorrect(){        
    `when`(mockContext.getString(R.string.res1)).thenReturn("aaa")
     Product().start(mockContext)
}
```

Mocking something doesn't mean that is gonna work on everything that is using it but for that reference, the specified behavior is mocked, so you have to make your implementation receives the mocked argument somehow.

Comment: I understand what you purpose but I was not looking for a dependency injection solution android has a built in getString function which is wired to the context object

Comment: You can't say `getString` anywhere, is not "built in". You can only say `getString` if the invoking class descends from context or has access to it (activity or fragment by example). So if your question is other then you should edit it to make it reflect what you actually want. Are you looking to ask for how to test a fragment method? Are you looking to ask how to use the resources on unit testing/roboelectric?

Comment: I guess so, i was looking for resource mocking by the way it’s written in the description